# Validation for user, email and password doesn't works

Tags: java, database, validation, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am having a problem on validating email and password, whether it belongs to a registered member or not. I'm using NetBeans, and created a database with table `members`. I have set up the connection pool and filled my members table.

After having implemented the code, solved errors and watched few videos about NetBeans tutorial, I still can't figure out where I am missing it. I'am Stuck there since 4 days and kinda lost now. Hope you guys could help me with it, thanks in advance.

**This is my members table data:**

```
 # | id |       email     | password |  name
------------------------------------------------
 1 |  1 | what@what.com   |   what   | Number 1 
 2 |  2 | fireup@fire.com |   fire   | Number 2
```

**This is the code for my LoginServlet:**

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/jed")
    private DataSource dsMembers;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String strName = request.getParameter("memberName");
        String strPassword = request.getParameter("memberPassword");
        String strEmail = request.getParameter("memberEmail");
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            conn = dsMembers.getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()){
                if((isValidEmail(strEmail))&& (strEmail.equals(rs.getString("email")))&& (strPassword.equals(rs.getString("password")))&&(strName.equals(rs.getString("name")))){
                    System.out.println("Success");

                   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                    session.setAttribute("name", strName);
                    session.setAttribute("email", strEmail);
                    response.sendRedirect(this.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/account.jsp");
                }
                else {
                    request.getSession().invalidate();
                    response.sendRedirect(this.getServletContext().getContextPath());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private boolean isValidEmail(String strEmail){
        if(strEmail.matches("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**This is the GlassFish Server log I been getting:**

> Info: WEB0671: Loading application [Project] at [/Project]
>       Info: Project was successfully deployed in 286 milliseconds.
>       Info: WEB0671: Loading application [Project] at [/Project]
>       Info: Project was successfully deployed in 247 milliseconds.
>       Info: Invalid User, Password or Email
>       Info: Invalid User, Password or Email
>       Warning: StandardWrapperValve[org.jedlibrary.lola.loan.ValidationServlet]: PWC1406:  Servlet.service() for servlet org.jedlibrary.lola.loan.ValidationServlet threw exception
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException 
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:524)
>       at org.jedlibrary.lola.loan.ValidationServlet.doPost(ValidationServlet.java:46) 
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688) 
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770) 
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860) 
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757) 
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) 
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: [Your problem is an IllegalStateException](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/ResponseFacade.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks Tom but if I comment it out, it will keep showing empty page whether is success or fail

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does not work, you are checking if the input is the email is `email`, the password is `password` and the name is `name`.

You should check against the `ResultSet` items, not constants. So for example, instead of

```
strEmail.equals("email")
```

you should write

```
strEmail.equals(rs.getString("email"))
```

**Edit:**

You have missed something else: you do not check the whole `ResultSet`. The first result does not match your provided data, so you invalidate the session at once. You should only invalidate it, when none of the items are matching.

This would solve your problem:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    if (isValidEmail(strEmail) && strEmail.equals(rs.getString("email")) && strPassword.equals(rs.getString("password")) && strName.equals(rs.getString("name"))) {
        System.out.println("Success");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("name", strName);
        session.setAttribute("email", strEmail);
        response.sendRedirect(this.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/account.jsp");
        return;
    }
}
request.getSession().invalidate();
response.sendRedirect(this.getServletContext().getContextPath());
```

**My final note:** you should *never* implement login this way (even for a homework), selecting the full table, for just one record is simply a waste of resources.

You should use a `PreparedStatement` with the statement like `select * from members where name = ?` and check if there is a result and the password and e-mail are appropriate (I assumed here, that name is unique in the database).

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing out, meskobalazs but what should I change it to or remove, needed help if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks meskobalazs, I just changed it but still get the same error log.

Comment: Yes, log is from GlassFish Server tag